# Creating multiple appointments in Outlook in one request?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I was looking at this [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84321/Setting-up-an-MS-Outlook-Appointment-Csharp.aspx) and seems pretty straight forward, now I know with a .ICS I can set multiple appointments, though opening .ICS files in blackberry does not work.  I was wondering if there was any way to code multiple appointments into one email?

Any advice would be welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about multiple single disconnected appointments within the same email I'm almost sure this is not possible, if you talk about recurring ones then you have good chances.

about opening .ICS with a blackberry you can google this and find something, eg:

> Basically, in order for the blackberry to import the appointment the
>   ICS file must contain a "METHOD:REQUEST" line. That is it. Normally
>   forwarded ICS appointments will have METHOD:PUBLISH. Here are the
>   steps to fix an ICS file.
>
> 1. Download the ICS file to your PC
> 2. Edit the ICS file using a text editor and add METHOD:REQUEST (or
>      replace METHOD:PUBLISH with METHOD:REQUEST)
> 3. Forward the modified ICS file to your blackberry.
> 4. Success!

http://forums.crackberry.com/native-apps-f152/ics-calendar-attachment-workaround-237230/